# Can I mix compile time string comparison with MPL templates?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-mpl

I got this compile time string comparison from another thread using constexpr and C++11 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721813/compile-time-assert-for-string-equality). It works with constant strings like "OK"

```
    constexpr bool isequal(char const *one, char const *two) {
        return (*one && *two) ? (*one == *two && isequal(one + 1, two + 1))
        : (!*one && !*two);
    }
```

I am trying to use it in the following context:

```
 static_assert(isequal(boost::mpl::c_str<boost::mpl::string<'ak'>>::value, "ak"), "should not fail");
```

But it gives me an compilation error of static_assert expression is not an constant integral expression.

Can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `value` member of `mpl::c_str` is not marked as `constexpr`. Until the library authors decide to include support for `constexpr`, you are pretty much screwed, unless you are willing to modify your Boost code (or create your own version of `c_str`). If you decide to do so, the modification is quite simple: you just need to locate `BOOST_ROOT/boost/mpl/string.hpp` and replace this

```
template<typename Sequence>
struct c_str
{
    ...
    static typename Sequence::value_type const value[BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_STRING_SIZE+1] 
};

template<typename Sequence>
typename Sequence::value_type const c_str<Sequence>::value[BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_STRING_SIZE+1] =
{
    #define M0(z, n, data)                                                                      \
    mpl::aux_::deref_unless<BOOST_PP_CAT(i, n), iend>::type::value,
    BOOST_PP_REPEAT(BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_STRING_SIZE, M0, ~)
    #undef M0
    '\0'
};
```

by this

```
template<typename Sequence>
struct c_str
{
    ...
    static constexpr typename Sequence::value_type value[BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_STRING_SIZE+1] =
    {
        #define M0(z, n, data)                                                                      \
        mpl::aux_::deref_unless<BOOST_PP_CAT(i, n), iend>::type::value,
        BOOST_PP_REPEAT(BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_STRING_SIZE, M0, ~)
        #undef M0
        '\0'
    };
};

// definition still needed
template<typename Sequence>
constexpr typename Sequence::value_type c_str<Sequence>::value[BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_STRING_SIZE+1];
```

---

Hmm, after digging a bit more, it turns out the problem is more complex than I thought. In fact, static constants can be used in constexpr; the true problem is that `c_str<T>::value` is an array, and your function takes pointers as parameters. As a consequence, the compiler needs to decay the array, which boils down to *taking the address of its first element*. Since addresses are a runtime concept, it is not possible to take the address of an object in a constexpr.

To solve the issue, I tried to write a second version of `isequal` that operates on arrays rather than on pointers:

```
template <int N, int M>
constexpr bool isequal(char const (&one)[N], char const (&two)[M], int index)
{
    return (one[index] && two[index]) ?
        (one[index] == two[index] && isequal(one, two, index + 1)) :
        (!one[index] && !two[index]);
}

template <int N, int M>
constexpr bool isequal(char const (&one)[N], char const (&two)[M])
{
    // note: we can't check whether N == M since the size of the array
    // can be greater than the actual size of the null-terminated string
    return isequal(one, two, 0);
}

constexpr char hello[] = "hello";
static_assert(isequal(hello, hello), "hello == hello");
constexpr char zello[] = "zello";
static_assert(!isequal(hello, zello), "hello != zello");
constexpr char hel[] = "hel";
static_assert(!isequal(hello, hel), "hello != hel");
```

Unfortunately, this code does not work with `mpl::c_str`; in fact, the problem is that static const arrays are not compile-time values, unlike integral constants. So we're back the beginning: unless `value` is marked as `constexpr`, there is no way to use it in a constant expression.

As to why the code I gave initially fails, I can't answer right now as my version of gcc (4.6) [fails to compile it altogether](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900242/error-with-constexprgcc-error-a-brace-enclosed-initializer-is-not-allowed-h)...

After updating gcc, it turns out `value` needs to be defined outside the class, even though it is declared and initialized in the class (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8016780/20984)). I edited the code above with the correction.

Comment: I am trying the code, it looks like the static_assert now works. But the sample code of BOOST MPL fails:


    typedef boost::mpl::string<'hell', 'o wo', 'rld'> hello;

    typedef boost::mpl::push_back<hello, boost::mpl::char_<'!'> >::type hello2;

    BOOST_ASSERT(0 == std::strcmp(boost::mpl::c_str<hello2>::value, "hello world!"));

Comment: It fails in the link time saying the boost::mpl::string<'hell', 'o wo', 'rld'> is not found

Comment: Ok, I updated gcc, and I think the problem is that even if `value` is initialized in the class, it still needs to be defined outside (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8016780/20984). I edited the code in my answer.